# Nightwatch - Cannot click on elements in Safari (Catalina)

Tags: javascript, safari, nightwatch

- Nightwatch: 1.3.4
- Safari: 13.0
- OS X: 10.15.3

I'm trying to set up my tests for Safari using Nightwatch.js and I'm running into a roadblock. For some reason, I'm unable to click on anything (whereas with the other browsers, I can).

Here's a simple test that fails -->

```
browser.url('https://www.google.com')
browser.waitForElementPresent('#gbqfbb')
browser.click('#gbqfbb')
```

Answer (score 0):

This works much better with the latest Safari Technology Preview. Install that and then replace your server_path for Safari with a bash shell script containing `/Applications/Safari\ Technology\ Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/safaridriver  --port 4445`